# websocket connection through cloudflared tunnel - quasar

Tags: web, websocket, proxy, cloudflare, quasar

> I created a tunnel for a quasar app. Then i created another tunnel to connect my front-end with my ruby on rails backend. I managed to configure the communication between both but I am missing the websocket connection for the hot reloading.

### This is my quasar config file

```
env: {
        API: ctx.dev
          ? 'https://example.com/api'
          : 'http://example.com/api/'
      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
    devServer: {
      https: false,
      port: 3000,
      open: true, // opens browser window automatically
      proxy: {
        // proxy all requests starting with /api to your API
        '/api': {
          target: ctx.dev
            ? 'https://example.com/'
            : 'http://example.com/api/',
          changeOrigin: true,
          pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '/api/v1'
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

### I tried this:

```
'/ws': {
          target: ctx.dev
            ? 'https://example.com:3000/' // here i set the url generated by cloudflared for front-end
            : 'http://example.com/api/', // doesn't matter for now
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
```